# django: Call to remote service kills python

Tags: django, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a django app that communicates with remote service (on my VPN but not hosted locally). I can successfully communicate with the service via the django shell but when I try to call the exact same function, posting the information from a webform, the development server dies.

I would have thought the shell and the development server would behave exactly the same way. The only thing I could think of was that the shell might be more 'patient', waiting for a response?

The communication happens via protocol buffers.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

The developpement server is single-threaded so if you open another connection it hangs the server.

You could try for dev purposes : http://github.com/jaylett/django_concurrent_test_server

works very well for me

Or use a real configuration, apache+wsgi for example

Comment: This looked perfect but sadly this didn't work. The server died exactly the same as before. Have you had success using this?

Comment: what didnt work  ? Apache or concurrent server ?
precise how you connect to remote service and which type of service.

Comment: The concurrent server died in the same way. The remote service connection is via Google protocol buffers.